# Is there a way to create a user who can only add but not edit/remove product in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, products, permissions, user-roles, role

I wonder whether there is a way to further restrict an magento website editor's role to the followings:

1) after login to magento, the editor is only able to add product to a certain category

2) the editor is not able to edit or remove existing products

3) the admin has to review all the products the editor added, before making products public.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requests seem tailored for this extension: [Aitoc Advanced Permissions](http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html).

1. ..>Edit Role>Advanced Permisssions > Allow manage own products only
2. ..>Edit Role>Advanced Permisssions > Limit Access to Store Views/Categories
3. System>Configuration>Advanced>Admin > Products Approve

These are very close to what you need. There are a lot of settings with which you can play to obtain the desired behavior.

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted ?! When you downvote, you are encouraged to leave an explanation, if not by mistake..

Comment: I don't know who devote your answer, which is clearly wrong. I just upvoted it. What you proposed definitely solved the problem, the extension is exactly what I need!